# Bearer token for external logins

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin

How can I get the Bearer token for users that have signed up through external login provider in MVC5?

For users with local account we can send a POST with username/password/grant_type to /token and receive the token and make authorized calls to protected endpoints by attaching the token as a header.

With external logins there is no password for users and I can't see how we can get the bearer token, any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the google/facebook/etc access token? It should be available in the AccessToken property in the OnAuthenticated event/callback of the Provider for the katana authentication middleware.

```
var fb = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = "...",
    AppSecret = "...",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "ExternalCookie",
    Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = async ctx =>
            {
                var access_token = ctx.AccessToken;
                ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", access_token));
            }
    }
};
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fb);
```

Comment: This code doesn't work for me `ctx.Identity.AddClaim`, so I use the `UserManager` to add a `Claim` manually, not good :(

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception. It just doesn't insert a claim in the database. I am wonder, why? I saw the same code in Building Modern Web Apps Jump Start (Module 3) http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/building-modern-web-apps-jump-start

Comment: It doesn't add the claim to the DB because the ctx.Identity is unrelated to the database -- ctx.Identity is the in-memory object that represents the identity of the user for the current HTTP request.